# How to get community baseURL using flow not apex in salesforce?

Tags: visual-workflow, lightning-community, screen-flow

I want to get a community baseURL using flow in salesforce.

Comment: so, what did you try?  you'll need to query `Site` using the developerName of the Experience; then query `SiteDetail` using the Site `Id` to get field `SecureUrl`

Answer (score 0):

I have pretty much the same question ([Salesforce site URL dynamic domain name](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/401197/salesforce-site-url-dynamic-domain-name)) and got a successful answer, but one that uses VF.

My best attempt was to create a record-triggered flow (no matter what) and add two "get records" boxes (2nd after the 1st).

Get records 1: "Get the Site Id" condition "Name = [name of site]". Got the "SiteId" variable/field.

Get records 2: "Get the SecureUrl from SiteDetail" where DurableId = SiteId (got from box 1).

Regrettably it doesn't work. First "get records" works fine (I get the site id), but the second "get records" gets zero records (I even tried putting the site Id hardcoded into the second box and got zero records)...

I guess this is the pathway but can't figure out why I can't get the SecureUrl...

Answer (score -3):

Use below formula

LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_260, FIND( '/services', $Api.Partner_Server_URL_260))

Comment: This works for an internal URL, but does not necessarily correlate to an experience site URL.

Comment: The explanation is as important as the solution itself.

Comment: No this is not a way to get community baseURL It is getting only baseOrgURL

@jeevi