# Salesforce site URL dynamic domain name

Tags: formula, force.com-sites

I need to create a formula field to register an invitation URL (to be sent via email) to a contact, where the URL is a (publicly accessed) Salesforce Site.

Here is the thing. The site URL is **[org].my.salesforce-sites.com/[path]** and I understand that this URL changes from Sandbox to Production.

Also, the URL will end with a parameter (**?id=[some_id]**) based on the invitation record.

How can I "build" the full URL so that I can use that field in an email template?

(I found some formulae, but those aren't able to provide the "salesforce-sites" part of the URL I need...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So, I solved this with a VF email plus custom component with component controller

### Here's the component controller class

```
/**
 * Component controller for various VF Components that need dynamic buttons
 * Use cases to date
 *  1 - Dynamic button in a VF email to a Help_Center Experience Cloud page
 */

public inherited sharing class ButtonComponentCtrl {

    public String siteDeveloperName {get; set;}

    /**
     * experienceCloudBaseUrl
     * reference: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/247372/2602
     * @return baseURL of an experience cloud site which is independent of org (PROD, QA, dev, etc)
     */
    public String experienceCloudBaseUrl {
        get {
            if (experienceCloudBaseUrl == null) {
                Site[] sites = [SELECT Id FROM Site WHERE Name = :siteDeveloperName];
                if (!sites.isEmpty()) {
                    SiteDetail siteDetail = [SELECT SecureURL FROM SiteDetail WHERE DurableId = :sites[0].Id];
                    experienceCloudBaseUrl = siteDetail.SecureUrl+
                        (siteDetail.SecureUrl.endsWith('/')     // PROD behaves differently than test
                            ? 's'
                            : '/s')    ;
                }
            }
            return experienceCloudBaseUrl;
        }
        private set;
    }
}
```

### and the VF component (to display a clickable button)

```
<!--
 - Designed to support button images with dynamic links to experience cloud sites
    Reference: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000384022&type=1
 -->

<apex:component id="ExperienceCloudButton" controller="ButtonComponentCtrl" access="global">
    <apex:attribute name="buttonContentAssetDevName" type="String" description="Content Asset developer name for the button image"/>
    <apex:attribute name="buttonWidth" type="String" description="CSS width for button"/>
    <apex:attribute name="experienceSiteApiName" type="String" assignTo="{!siteDeveloperName}" description="Site Api name used to get baseUrl independent of org"/>
    <apex:attribute name="orgBaseUrl" type="String" description="Org's BaseUrl"/>
    <apex:attribute name="pathToExperiencePage" type="String" description="Path (relative) to page including any params"/>

    <apex:outputLink value="{!experienceCloudBaseUrl}{!pathToExperiencePage}">
        <apex:image id="clickableButton"
                    width="{!buttonWidth}"
                    value="{!orgBaseUrl}/file-asset-public/{!buttonContentAssetDevName}?oid={!$Organization.Id}"  alt="clickableButton"/>
    </apex:outputLink>
</apex:component>
```

### and usage in the VF email template

```
...
<c:ExperienceCloudButton buttonContentAssetDevName="ClickHereButton"
    buttonWidth="300px"
    experienceSiteApiName="MySiteApiName"
    orgBaseUrl="{!relatedTo.Base_Url__c}"
    pathToExperiencePage="/myPage?param1={!relatedTo.MyField1__c}&param2={!relatedTo.MyField2__c}"/> 
...
```

### and a convenience field on the relatedTo Object

```
Base_Url__c (Text)

Data Type   Formula      
LEFT($Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_570, FIND('/services',$Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_570))
```

Comment: It's funny I've been trying to do this via a flow, but I can't. The first query (getting the Site Id) works fine, but the second one (getting the SecureUrl from SiteDetail) doesn't, even if I write the Site Id directly into the query (I mean, the "get records" box)... I will have to move to development mode...